# iOS 16 prevent UIViewController from rotation

Tags: ios, screen-rotation, ios16

I have an UIViewController that supports all UIInterfaceOrientationMasks
But, in one certain case I need to prevent it from rotation
Before iOS 16 i was just handling this case like this

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return !screenRecorderIsActive
}
```

And everything was working fine
After update to iOS 16 my controller keeps rotating and I can't find a way to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoted from the [iOS 16 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-16-release-notes):

> [UIViewController shouldAutorotate] has been deprecated is no longer
> supported. [UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation] has
> been deprecated and replaced with [UIViewController
> setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations].
>
> **Workaround**: Apps relying on shouldAutorotate should reflect their
> preferences using the view controllers supportedInterfaceOrientations.
> If the supported orientations change, use `-[UIViewController
> setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterface

To implement dynamic supported interface orientations, you can use some code like this:

```
var screenRecorderIsActive: Bool {
    didSet {
        setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
    }
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if screenRecorderIsActive {
        return [.landscape] // For example, or a variable representing the orientation when the condition was set
    }
    return [.all]
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've read release notes 
And I successfully adopted this behaviour to support orientation changes in iOS 16
But what should I do to prevent rotation in this case?

Comment: @DmitryZheshinsky I extended my answer a bit

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I need to prevent auto rotation not based upon a particular orientation, but rather based upon what you're doing in the app and what kind of hardware your device has.  And, I need to continue to support iOS versions all the way back to 9.3.  These updates forced me to to do the following:

The new functions aren't available back in 9.3, so I have to do some checking if the version of iOS is 16.x.  If so, then I had to implement supportedInterfaceOrientations so that the current user interface orientation is queried and only returns TRUE if the orientation requested is the same as the current user interface orientation.  In other words, don't allow a change.

Also, since both returning from the background or rotations or events from other view controllers can change my logic choice for which orientations are allowed, I had to be sure to call the setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations method when returning from the background or any other time I needed to prevent auto rotation.

Again, I had to wrap this code in iOS version checks.  Finally I had to implement things the old way for older versions of iOS.

I was very disappointed that such a breaking change was introduced.  Yes, the methods were deprecated for a long time, but the new methods weren't introduce until 16.0 - and even more critically, my code does different things when using the front landscape camera now available on the iPad 10, so I had to wait until I had a unit in my hands to uncover these issues.